# JSON DeserializeObject shows 0

Tags: c#, json, xamarin

hello i've got some problems in c#(xamarin)
i followed XXX tutorials about pharsing..
I only need the Value.
Can someone tell me how i solve that problem?

my Json:

```
{
   "Header":{
      "Version":5,
      "Device":"80",
      "Timestamp":1610066048
   },
   "Data":{
      "Inputs":[
         {
            "Number":2,
            "AD":"A",
            "Value":{
               "Value":62.0,
               "Unit":"1"
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "Status":"OK",
   "Status code":0
}
```

C#

```
var client = new WebClient();
            string json = client.DownloadString("https://XXXXXXX.com/heizung.php");
             Value1 news = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Value1>(json);

            Ausgabe.Text = news.Value;
```

My Class

```
  public class Header
    {
        public int Version { get; set; }
        public string Device { get; set; }
        public int Timestamp { get; set; }
    }

    public class Value1
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public string Unit { get; set; }
    }

    public class Input
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public string AD { get; set; }
        public Value1 Value { get; set; }
        
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public List<Input> Inputs { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public Header Header { get; set; }
        public Data Data { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public int Statuscode { get; set; }
    }
```

Thanks, i hope y'all have a nice day.

Comment: Have you tried renaming `Value1` to `Value`?

Comment: you mean public class Value1 -> public class Value?

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the class.

Comment: than i get a error at (public string Value { get; set; })        Value": Member names cannot be of the enclosing type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deserialize Root object and track value down:

```
Root news = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);

Ausgabe.Text = news.Data.Inputs[0].Value.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should deserialize your json as a `Root` class:

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
```

After the root object is deserialized you can select whatever value you need. E.g.:

```
var values = root.Data.Inputs.Select(i => i.Value.Value); // string sequence
```

Comment: when i do is, i'm not getting " Ausgabe.Text = news.Value "

Comment: What does `I'm not getting` mean? You have an exception? Also why `Value1.Value` is a string instead of number?

Comment: when i do this, i m getting* sorry. .  but my problem is solved ;) thank you too - it helps me learning ;)